# How can I control a PANIC button on Android?

Tags: android, button, hardware, hardware-interface

I want to create an application which listens to events from a specific button (hardware button) and triggers some event.

For example, think about a PANIC button function, when some button is kept pressed for 5 seconds, this will trigger some ALERT (suppose sending an sms message).

I have not yet found a way to make this.

Please keep in mind that this MUST BE a HARDWARE BUTTON and not a software button (might in an activity).

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

> I do not find yet a way to make this.

In your own activity, you can watch for whatever buttons you want via `onKeyDown()`.

Outside of your own activity, what you want is not possible, except via firmware modifications.

Comment: Maybe just rooting. Is there some kind of systemwide event hooking in Linux? In Windows, there is. Still, a very dangerous proposition.

Comment: It's actually possible for some buttons. For example long pressing the search button will trigger the Intent android.intent.action.SEARCH_LONG_PRESS. Some sms applications use this for quick compose screens.

Comment: @danvari: You are correct, I forgot that. However, that is still a system-defined long press (not 5 seconds as the OP requested).

Comment: Will the long press intent fire while the button is still held down?  If so, perhaps the application could see if it remains down long enough to qualify.  But we also have to ask if it will happen at all when the keyguard is locked.